# getElementsByName instead of getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have a computation fare using the `getElementById.innerHTML` the total fare showing using `<h5 id="totalFare"></h5>` but instead if getElementByID i want to parse in getElementsByName by using a `<input type="number" name="totalFare" readonly />` i'm searching a lot page to find out the answer, below is my codes. i hope you can help me.

```
<input type="number" id="adults" min="0" onkeyup="calculate()"  name="booking[adults]" class="validate" value="0" required>

<input type="number" id="children" min="0" onkeyup="calculate()" name="booking[children]" class="validate" value="0"   required>

<input type="number" id="senior" min="0" onkeyup="calculate()" name="booking[senior]" class="validate" value="0"  required>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate(){
    var adults   = document.getElementById("adults").value;
    var children = document.getElementById("children").value;
    var senior = document.getElementById("senior").value;
    var Fare = document.getElementById("hideFare").value;


    var values = fare(adults, children, senior, Fare);

    console.log(values)
    document.getElementById("totalFare").innerHTML = values.totalFare;

  }
    function fare(x, y, z, a) {
    var res = {};
    res.totalFare = (( x  * a) + (y * (a *.80)) + (z * (a *.80)))
    return res
  }

</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to use getElementsByName instead of getElementById but i know how todo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getElementsByName` like below.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" id="testing" value="This is a value" />
```

The `document.getElementsByName("test")` gives you something like an array (called a collection of elements since there could be multiple elements with the same name), so the `[0]` is there to get the first index which is the value you wanted. Look at the link below for more information.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: Thanks Aniket, i used this code 'document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value = values.totalFare;' and its working. likewise what is the meaning of [0]?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("test")` gives you an array which in this case would be `["This is a value"]`. The 0 is there to select the first index from the array which is the value you wanted.

Thanks for pointing that out. I'll add that into the answer. Any other questions?

Comment: @AniketG Just to correct that `document.getElementsByName` return an array-like object called a collection, it is not an array. It is a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a NodeList object.

Comment: @hcheung I actually didn't know that. That's my bad. But the concept is the same. I'll fix my post